# Rails: Hstore column: search for the same value in all keys in fastest way

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hash, hstore

I have a table (over 100,000 records) with hstore column that has 12 keys. I want to search the hstore column for a value that can be in any of the 12 keys. What is the fastest way of doing this?
My current OR query takes 300 ms which is too long.

```
value_to_search = "my_hstore_value"
keys = [1,2,3,4]

keys.each do |key|
conditions << ["hstore_column @> hstore('#{key}', '#{value_to_search.upcase}')"]
end

MyTable.where(conditions.join(' OR '))
```

Which creates something like ->

```
MyTable.where("hstore_column @> hstore('1', 'my_hstore_value') OR "hstore_column @> hstore('2', 'my_hstore_value')" OR "hstore_column @> hstore('3', 'my_hstore_value')"")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had done following things to improve the performance which helped me a lot.

1. Added `Gin` composite index with required columns. You don't need to index for specific key as it will work for any key when you use operator `@>`. You could also try Gist index as well. If you need to check equality check then please create appropriate `BTREE` index. Indexing will be used based on operators (`@>`, `=` etc) you have used in your queries. So please decide what index you need to create. Adding appropriate indexing will drastically improve the performance.
2. If you want to quickly get something working, you can create a GIN index on data::text. This will index a stringified version of the json. Then you can query against the stringified version with data::text ILIKE '%foo%'.